# Bootstrap, using nested grid to show a title and form buttons in a card-header

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a nested card header and would like to display my title, and two form + submit buttons (edit, delete) in a row.  (The forms are only submit buttons)  The first example works fine, but I need to use forms and a nested submit button instead of just buttons.  That is shown in the second block.  The submit buttons have a margin issue, I'm guessing from being nested within the form element.  Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way.
[visual of what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnTBs.png)

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-md-10 card-title">
                            myThreadTitle
                        </div>
                        <button class="col-md-1 btn btn-warning btn-sm rounded-0">
                            Edit
                        </button>
                        <button class="col-md-1 btn btn-warning btn-sm rounded-0">
                            Delete
                        </button>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-md-10 card-title">
                            {{ $thread->title }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <form 
                                action="" 
                                method="POST"
                            >
                                <button 
                                    type="submit"    
                                    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-0"
                                >
                                    Delete
                                </button>    
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear what exactly your question/the problem you are having is?

Comment: Hey FK, when I nest the forms inside the col-md-1, the margins on the form's submit buttons hang over the row.  Also there seems to be added space in between the form's submit buttons in the 2nd example.

Comment: edit added a link to a picture of what happens to the buttons when I use a submit button inside the form